# jquery trying to bind to element that exists later

Tags: jquery

I am creating an input text box when a dropdown menu changes like so:

```
var html;

$('#communtiyDropdown').on('change', function () {
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/vendorProject/api/connection/getVendorItems?community=" + $("#communtiyDropdown").val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (results) {
                 $.each(results, function (key, value) {
                   html += "<td><input type='text' name='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' id='vendorDropdown' class='vendorDropdown' value='" + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].split(' ')[0] + "' /></td>";
                 });
            }
            $("#tableData").html(html);
      });
});
```

and then I am adding autocomplete to each text box like so:

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    console.log(availableTags);

    $('.vendorDropdown').on('keyup', function () {
        console.log('here');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

but my problem, autocomplete is not working, it does not appear and I do not get errors in my console log either.... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: use bind delegate or live in place of on

Comment: You are creating multiple elements with the same id!? That's not what's causing your problem but also needs to be fixed.

Comment: `it does appear ` or `it does not appear `?

Comment: did you try placing the autocomplete code inside the onchange event, after elements are created? And yes you should fix the fact that they all have the same id

Comment: @user979331 A JSFiddle link is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your success callback, like so (also fixed ID to be indexed):

```
success: function (results) {

    var html = '';

    $.each(results, function (key, value) {
        html += "<td><input type='text' name='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' id='vendorDropdown"+[i]+"' class='vendorDropdown' value='" + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].split(' ')[0] + "' /></td>";
    });

    $("#tableData").html(html);
    $('.vendorDropdown').autocomplete({source: availableTags});
}
```